# How to exclude specific tables from list of tables?

Tags: table-of-contents

I made a copy of the latex document here
Right now I have two tables, one being used in the title.tex for names and second in the revision_history.tex. I am trying to remove these two tables from the LOT so I can start the numbering from 1 for the actual table in the documents.

Basically I want to tell Latex which tables are NOT tables and to just ignore them.

Comment: Remove the table caption that you would like to be ignored.

Comment: For example if you remove the line `\captionof{table}{A nice table}\label{tbl:nicetablelesstable}`, then that table won't be listed anywhere.

Comment: @hesham I understand that but the numbering won't be right.

Comment: @hesham as in it would still count the table without the caption as a table

Comment: The proposed duplicate is for figures but for tables it works in exactly the same way.

Comment: @Marijn no it does not, you can see how the figures start from 2, I don't want that, I want it to start from 1 still

Comment: @AJ98 in that case you can use `\caption*{some caption}`. (with a `*`).

Comment: Note that this still requires `\usepackage{caption}` to work.

Comment: @Marijn sorry but no \caption*{} does not work either

Comment: @AJ98 it works on a simple document, I tried it myself. If it does not work in your real document then you should provide a minimal reproducible example document to your question (instead of a link to an Overleaf project) that shows your exact situation. If you don't do this then we are forced to guess, which may result in suggesting solutions that don't work for you, as you have seen now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Remove the table(s) caption that you would like to be ignored

2.) Add `\setcounter{table}{0}` before the actual table that you would like to be started as number 1 in your main document.

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Comment: If you want to keep the caption of un-numbered table(s) while hidden from the list of tables, then follow @Marijn comments.

Comment: yes it did but I'm worried what to do in case I get a table in the middle of other tables? Don't think I can use this method then

Comment: You mean you want an un-numbered table (and also hidden from the LOT) in the middle of normally numbered tables?

Comment: yes exactly, do you reckon that is possible? I basically want the ability of excluding tables from the LOT in random

Comment: In that case try `\captionof*{table}` with the astresic instead of `\captionof{table}` for the un-numbered table in the middle of numbered tables.

Comment: it did not work sorry to say, I don't know what is wrong

Comment: If you've already loaded `\usepackage{caption}` and still did not work, then better follow @Marijn and post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we can help you better.